# TFS On Premise: API to Create Backlog Item using Postman

Tags: tfs

We have TFS on premise and i want to create a backlog Item using API.

I am able to get items from TFS but i am not able to create. Any guidance please

I am using the following path for getting the items.

/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=

So after trying the solution below in Postman i get this.

Hi,

http://*.*.*.*:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/$Product Backlog Items?api-version=5.0

application/json-patch+json

Body:

So i tried what you mention but i get this error

```
                <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
                <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Actually it is not debugging. TFS has an API end point to get the list of backlog items that is the path. I need to know how can i create a TFS backlog item using Restful API.

Comment: You've provided practically no details about the problem. Please update your question to include a **specific error** and **code that reproduces it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the `Request Body` and use the `PATCH` method to create a work item:

Please see [Create a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/wit/work-items?view=tfs-2018#create-a-work-item) for details.

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": { string }
        "value": { string or int, depending on the field }
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value":
        {
            "rel": { string },
            "url": { string },
            "attributes":
            {
                { name/value pairs }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

You can also use below PowerShell sample calling the REST API to create a PBI (add other fields based on your requirement):

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$projectName = "0511ScrumTFVC",
   [string]$workItemType = "Product Backlog Item",
   [string]$user = "Domain\user",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "0831-PBI-Test"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    "value": "0511ScrumTFVC"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
    "value": "0511ScrumTFVC\\Sprint 1"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Tags",
    "value": "Tag0831"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity",
    "value": "Development"
  },

  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort",
    "value": "8"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea",
    "value": "Business"
  }
]
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/workitems/"+"$"+"$($workItemType)?api-version=2.2"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $json -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems you are using the unsupported `api-version=5.0`. The api version `5.x` is only supported in VSTS. For on-premise TFS 2017 the supported version is `3.x`, TFS2018 is `4.x`, and it's forward compatible, e.g `2.x` is also supported in TFS 2017 and 2018.

So just have a try with the `api-version=2.2`... it works on my side.

The second error means the request body format is incorrect. You can follow my PowerShell sample and just change the correspond values for the body, then try it again.

Besides, you can reference this blog to create work items in TFS: [Create Work Items in Visual Studio Online with Nintex Workflow 2010](https://community.nintex.com/community/build-your-own/blog/2017/06/29/create-work-items-in-visual-studio-online-with-nintex-workflow-2010)

Comment: Hi,

http://*.*.*.*:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/$Product Backlog Items?api-version=5.0

application/json-patch+json

Body:


So i tried what you mention but i get this error

                    <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
                    <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>

Comment: I manage to get that sorted. Now i am able to use the method. but Postman returns me this error. 
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    "typeKey": "VssPropertyValidationException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000

Comment: Basically i want to use Nentix to create a TFS item.

Comment: @user592514 What't the version of TFS do you use? Seems you are using the unsupported `api-version=5.0`. The api version `5.x` is only supported in VSTS. For on-premise TFS 2017 the supported version is `3.x`, TFS2018 is `4.x`, and it's forward compatible, e.g `2.x` is also supported in TFS 2017 and 2018. So just have a try with the `api-version=2.2`... it works on my side. Also the second error means the request body format is incorrect. You can follow my PowerShell sample and just change the correspond values for the body, then try it again.

Comment: @user592514 Have you resolved the issue by the updated answer? any update?

Comment: Hi yes this solved the problem. I was able to integrate but the problem was Nintex do not support Patch method in office 365. TFS uses PATCH method only.